# how to move to another route on ajax success

Tags: vue.js, axios

hello guys i m new to vue, i m using vue 2.5 and i does lot of google and found this this.$router.push('/login'); but i was not working so got little with confuse how i can achieve this.

i want to redirect to login url when user successfully register  then i want to redirect user to login url

here is my code

```
  let res = {
              phone: this.registerData.phone,
              companyname: this.registerData.companyname,
              username: this.registerData.username,
              email: this.registerData.email,
              password: this.registerData.password,
             }

         // console.log(res);
            var _this = this
            var vm = this.hasErrors
            var _vm = this.errorMessage
            this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users', res)
            .then(function (response) {

           if(response.status=== 200){
            console.log('move');

            this.$router.push('/login');
           }else{
            console.log('unknow');
           }
            })
```

note i want to redirect user to login url after he register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use `this.$router.push('/login');`

instead of `_this.$router.push('/login');`

Comment: what difference between this and _this  why normal this not working

Comment: Just simple: 
In your code you have `var _this = this`(should be const but nvm) that's why you should use `_this`.
`this` is different for every scope,  On top of method you can catch and save `this` from VUE scope (or component ...) , so inside  of your method you try call `this.` what belong to axios,  when trying call vue element $router. Thats why on top of every method etc in vue you want to create `const _this = this` to have access fom every palce in this method to vue this

You can read more about that: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Answer (score 1):

You can also use arrow functions and use the `this` keyword inside the callback, e.g.

```
let res = {
    phone:this.registerData.phone,
    companyname: this.registerData.companyname,
    username: this.registerData.username,
    email: this.registerData.email,
    password: this.registerData.password,
}

// console.log(res);
var vm = this.hasErrors
var _vm = this.errorMessage
this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users', res)
.then((response) => {
    if(response.status=== 200){
        console.log('move');

        this.$router.push('/login');
    }else{
        console.log('unknow');
    }
})
```